# Appropiate configuration for network structure

Tags: routing, network-shares, dsl-modem

I need a configuration for sniffing data packets and accessing the internet from the sniffer machine. The system schema is something like this:

```
                             Linksys X1000 modem 
                            /                   \
 USB 3G Dongle     <->   Laptop               Custom Device using Ethernet
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX       192.168.1.2                      192.168.1.3
```

The modem is used for giving each device an local IP address, I want the custom device to access the internet using USB 3G dongle. And I need to sniff the data from custom device reaching the internet.

How may I accomplish something like this?

Comment: you can't sniff on the laptop interface that the dongle is attached to? that is the only segment in your diagram where that would be possible.

Comment: the problem is that i can't redirect the custom device's data to some other server on the internet via 3g dongle. How should I configure this system (the modem should be the router) to do something like that?

Comment: easiest answer is to get DSL service (since the modem is an ADSL modem/wifi router), and stop using the 3g dongle. Alternately, you could set up a PC on the WAN side of the router (I'm not certian the rotuer takes Ethernet for WAN though) and use it as an upstream router. I wouldn't recommend using the laptop to do it unless you don't need it for actual use.

Comment: Any one who has a idea?